# Trying to add a delete function with JavaScript, which needs to remove the whole form when I click it. I'm using bootstrap by the way

Tags: javascript, html

When I call the function I need it to remove basically everything. What should that function be? Tried using parentNode but couldn't figure out the logic out for that.

```
<form>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Ingredient"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Quantity"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-3">
            <select id="inputUnit" class="form-control">
              <option selected>g</option>
              <option>kg</option>
              <option>lb</option>
              <option>oz</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-1">
            <a id="remover" href="#" onclick="deleteFunction();return false;">
              <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `parentNode`, you just have to understand what it means.

The parentNode of the link is `form-group`. The parentNode of that is `form-row` and the parentNode of that is the form.

Also you need to pass in `this` to the function so it knows what element you are clicking on.

```js
function deleteFunction(el){
  el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```css
form{background:red;}
```

```html
<form>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Ingredient"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Quantity"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-3">
            <select id="inputUnit" class="form-control">
              <option selected>g</option>
              <option>kg</option>
              <option>lb</option>
              <option>oz</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-1">
            <a id="remover" href="#" onclick="deleteFunction(this);">
              <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true">X</i>
            </div>
        </div>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [remove()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_remove.asp) on the element you want to delete.

```
const deleteFunction = () => {
    document.querySelector('form').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, run the snippet below:

```js
//we are targeting the form with querySelector
var form = document.querySelector("form");
//function to remove form from DOM 
function remove() {
form.remove();
}
```

```html
<div>
<form>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Ingredient"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Quantity"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-3">
            <select id="inputUnit" class="form-control">
              <option selected>g</option>
              <option>kg</option>
              <option>lb</option>
              <option>oz</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-1">
            <a id="remover" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
   </form>
   </div>
   <div>
   <button onclick="remove()">delete</button>
   </div>
```

Comment: He wants to remove the form, not hiding ;)

Answer (score 0):

Give your form an "id", and delete it using JQuery (considering you're using it since you mentioned bootstrap).

```
<form id="form">
<div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Ingredient"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Quantity"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-3">
            <select id="inputUnit" class="form-control">
              <option selected>g</option>
              <option>kg</option>
              <option>lb</option>
              <option>oz</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-1">
            <a id="remover" href="#" onclick="deleteFunction();return false;">
              <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form
```

Two way of doing this in Jquery,

1. If you want to delete the form and it's child elements

```
$("#form").remove();
```

2. If you want to delete only the child elements of the form.

```
$("#form").empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user `remove()` to remove the element from DOM. Assign an ID to your form and select the element using `const myForm = document.getElementById('form')`. Then `myForm.remove();` remove it from DOM.

```js
function deleteFunction() {
  const myForm = document.getElementById('form');
  myForm.remove();
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Ingredient"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Quantity"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-3">
            <select id="inputUnit" class="form-control">
              <option selected>g</option>
              <option>kg</option>
              <option>lb</option>
              <option>oz</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-1">
            <a id="remover" href="#" onclick="deleteFunction();return false;">Delete
              <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

And this decision is from me. The `closest()` method is used here - referring to parent elements. And `remove()` method.

But if you just need to hide the form, then use this:

```
...
this.closest('form').style.display = 'none';
...
```

```js
let remove = document.querySelector('#remover');

remove.onclick = function() {
  this.closest('form').remove();
}
```

```html
<form>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Ingredient"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Quantity"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-3">
            <select id="inputUnit" class="form-control">
              <option selected>g</option>
              <option>kg</option>
              <option>lb</option>
              <option>oz</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-1">
            <a id="remover" href="#">remove
              <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
        </div>
   </form>
```